# How do I find the MAC address in Mac OS 9?

Tags: mac-address, mac-os-classic

I've never used a Mac in my life – now I have to find out the MAC address of Mac OS 9. I can't even find terminal or console there.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Apple Menu to the top left, under *Control Panels*? Maybe there's something related to networking?

Comment: Do [these](http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/security/os/macaddr.html) (last two sections) instructions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Click Control Panels, TCP/IP
>
> A dialog box will come up.
>
> Click File, Get Info
>
> A dialog box will come up.
>
> The address is listed as the Hardware address

This is the way you do it.

[Source](http://jafci.chem.purdue.edu/ethernet.html)

Comment: Please give attribution to the original site or author.

Comment: Forgot to do that, edited and fixed.